# Allow access to users after registration

Tags: php

Googlebots are crawling our recently developed website and if i search for images related to the products which are already uploaded in our website it is displaying our website images and if i go on clicking the image it is directly displaying the products information without asking for registration or signup please tell me how to fix this problem

Comment: ask for a session before showing the web

Comment: You can authenticate users in a hundred different ways. You might also consider some sort of `robots.txt` configuration for the website.

Comment: If you want practical help you should definitely provide more info on what you want to do and how

Comment: Find a new developer that can actually code. If something so basic doesn't work, it makes you wonder how poorly the rest of the site is built.